# Ending Grammar in 遅くなる前に、帰りや。

Tags: verbs

I do not understand the grammar behind 帰りや in 遅くなる前に、帰りや。The meaning I have for this sentence is "Please go home before becoming late." It looks as if it is a grammar form using verb stem + や, but I can't find anything about such a form. It also appears that it has the meaning of making a request. I'm hoping someone can point me to the actual grammar principle being used and/or explain it.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a dialect that means 帰りなさい.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it verb stem + や that creates the form?